# How not to raise other alarms in Nagios when Linux server is down?

Tags: nagios

Nagios reports when processes are down or when Filesystems are unmounted. But it reports all that when the Linux server is down. What do I need to configure to make sure when server is down only server down alarms are created but not the other alarms ?

Answer (score 2):

A host check that marks a host down will prevent services to notify.

Although, this will not always be the case in a standard configuration. A host check will be defined by your host check intervals, or will be done on-demand when a service state changes. If the service change will trigger a notification before the host is checked than you would receive a notification on your service, and short after on your host.

You could prevent this by setting the check/retry intervals on host checks a bit higher than the same intervals for service checks.

Host chekcs are [described in the Nagios manual](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/hostchecks.html).

Comment: Good answer! To add up, It may also happen if the check alive is not the default and for some reason returns unknown

Comment: Thanks Joffrey, Do you mean if service check/retry is 5/2 then change host values to 4/1 ?

Comment: @LinServFaulter, the exact values are not that abstract, it also depends on the duration of the check itself. But make sure you have a valid check (like icmp) to the host, and make sure it will will have lower check/interval values. You should test which values work for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are suggestions from my team mates to use service dependencies.

https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/dependencies.html

Which is better than changing intervals -> it will still raise other alarms at a reduced rate. But with service dependencies other alarms will not be raised at all.